# I can't get any data output from the database, i only get "0 results" as the else statement, what's the case?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wampserver

I'm having some troubles with fetching some database information with my php code.
All I'm getting is this message: "Connected successfully0 results".
Here's my code guys, thanks for the help in advance.

```
 <?php
    $servername = "example";
    $username = "example1";
    $password = "example2";
    $row = array();

    $conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected successfully";
    $sql = "Select Distinct subject from mobile_math_science_toc";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "Subject " ,$row["subject"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results ";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: Forget to select database!!

Comment: Didn't select the database

Comment: ^ What they said. I'm also curious about why you're calling the query twice? Once with the procedural style and then you're making it again in the row after, writing over the first result?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm new to php, this is my first day so I'm trying to find my way around :P, any help would be great and thanks for noticing the query problem dude.

Comment: @Saty Select database where ? I'm new to this.

Comment: If you're new, you should study the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password);
```

To

```
 $conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password, "<your database name>");
```

And

```
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
}
```

To

```
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add dbname while creating your connection to database. You can use `mysqli_num_rows` function to count no. of rows.

```
<?php
    $servername = "example";
    $username = "example1";
    $password = "example2";
    $dbname = "your_db_name"; // Specify your db-name here.

    $conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected successfully";

    $sql = "Select Distinct subject from mobile_math_science_toc";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    // Checking if there are some records available.
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "Subject " ,$row["subject"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results ";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Sure. Thanks for the suggestion. Earlier I added comments in code. Now I have added brief description too before the code. Hope that looks fine now.

Comment: @KeyurPanchal Yes it worked, I tried what you said and I got the info right from the Database. Sorry for not replying yesterday i was sick and i couldn't make it to work. Thanks for all the help, god bless you.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

While checking you got the data or not